# Is there a way to let another array or any other data structure hold references to certain values stored in another array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, reference

I am working on a Sudoku solver right now and currently the cells are represented as a 2d array of size 9x9.
`int[][] grid = new int[9][9];`

To address the different logic units in the grid (rows, columns, or boxes) I have subclasses to hold an array of size 9 to hold the digits in this unit `int[] values = new int[9];`

Minimum code:

```
public class SudokuSolver
{
   private abstract class SudokuSet
   { 
      int[] values; //gets initialized in constructor of subclasses
      ..
   }

   private class SudokuRow extends SudokuSet
   { 
      SudokuRow(int position)
      {
         for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
            values[i] = grid[position][i];
  
         ..
      }
      ..
   }

   int[][] grid = new int[9][9];

   SudokuSolver(int[][] g)
   {
       grid = g;
       ..
   }

   private void insertDigit(int x,int y,int d)
   {
      grid[y][x] = d;
      ..
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that `values` is always up to date with the logically connected parts of `grid`. In other words when I call insertDigit and it assigns a value to a position in the grid then I want to have every corresponding values attribute to be updated. So I want to have `values` hold references to the data in `grid`

Of course, I could do keep track of the inserted digit and also insert it manually in each logic unit `values` but as each cell appears in exactly 3 units it would be a bit of a bother and not as elegant. Also this project is meant to learn more Java coming from C/C++ so this is a good opportunity to understand how something like this is possible without actual pointers.

According to my research this is not possible with arrays of primitive types because e.g. when assigning `values[0] = grid[5][0]` it will actually copy the value. So I am not deadset on using arrays and I am happy to accept a different data structure.

I tried using ArrayList<Integer> because I thought Integers are objects (wrapper class of int), but it seems to not work either.

I tried something like

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

myList1.add(0);
myList1.add(1);

ArrayList<Integer> myList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

myList2.add(myList1.get(0));

myList1.set(0,5) //--> myList2.get(0) is still 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you do `myList1.set(0,5)` you are actually setting the content of `myList1[0]` to a different object, but `myList2[0]` is still pointing to the same object as it was before. You need an object where you can actually change a property, but that's not possible with the `Integer` class.

```
class IWrapper {

  public IWrapper(int val){
    value = val;
  }

  public int value;
}

ArrayList<IWrapper> myList1 = new ArrayList<IWrapper>();
ArrayList<IWrapper> myList2 = new ArrayList<IWrapper>();

myList1.set(0, new IWrapper(5));
myList2.set(0, myList1.get(0));
myList1.get(0).value = 3;
System.out.println(myList2.get(0).value);
```

But the bigger question is, if you want to be `myList1` and `myList2` to be in sync, why do you not just assign

```
myList2 = myList1;
```

This way, all changes you do to `myList1` will automatically show up also in `myList2` because they are in fact both pointing to the very same object ...

Comment: Thank you. I think that clears things up for me. The reason I cannot just do `myList1 = myList2` is that in the Sudoku program they have different sizes as one list (or in my original attempt the array) represent the whole grid (size 81) while the single logic units are of size 9.